# Як пояснити «і в головах низько»

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми

Як пояснити «і в головах низько»? Приклад вживання: «Він як не грюпне дверима перед тим як зайти в хату, то йому й в головах низько».

Comment: Ви маєте на увазі: (а) «яке значення в цього словосполучення» чи (б) «як сталося, що це словосполучення набуло такого значення»?

Comment: Цікавий вираз... Ніколи такий не чула.

Answer (score 6):

З різних джерел (хоч і не дуже авторитетних) — [1](https://www.ukrtvory.com.ua/frazeologizmi/f18.html), [2](https://supermif.com/frazeologizm/uuu.html), [3](https://dovidka.biz.ua/frazeologizmi-na-literu-u/), [4](http://all4zno.net/mova/info_mova/73-frazeologzmi-yak-mozhut-trapitis-u-zno-z-ukrayinsokoyi-movi-ta-lteraturi.html), [5](http://philologist.lg.sch.in.ua/gallery_and_documents/skrinjka_frazeologizmiv/?pvi=no&pvi=pvi), [6](https://totgor.com/info/gumoresku/browse.php?u=Oi8vZmFibGUuaW4udWEvZnJhemVvbG9naXptaS1uYS1saXRlcnUtdC8%3D&b=13), [7](https://sites.google.com/site/mrpresidentgovua/home/frazeologizmi):

> **У головах низько.** Незручно, бракує чогось, не по собі.
>
> > Раніш то бувало не дуже-то, а тепер таке пішло, що як не придумаєш чого, то наче тобі і в головах низько… (І. Микитенко, Дні юності, І, І, 2).

Ще приклад:

> От сусіда бог послав. Не чоловік, а кара господня. Йому й у головах низько, як не наведе на кого міліцію (Василь Захарченко).

Comment: Збиває з пантелику перше визначення 'незручно', бо якщо його наприклад підставити в моє речення - приклад то вийде галіматья

Comment: @piznajko, мається на увазі: не в прямому сенсі «фізично незручно», а в переносному «психологічно людина почуває себе некомфортно» (хоча, я так розумію, вираз походить саме від фізичного — спати незручно, коли в головах низько). Тобто така людина, що їй обов'язково треба грюкнути дверима, перш ніж у хату зайти, інакше почуватиметься «не в своїй тарілці» (частковий синонім). Навіщо грюкати, я не знаю: або справді прикмета така (не зробить — почуватиметься некомфортно), або це просто перебільшено образно описується, що людина дуже незграбна (як заходить, то (майже кожного разу) мимоволі грюкне).

Comment: Тобто якщо я правильно розумію речення в запитанні, то це аж переносне значення від переносного значення :). Пряме значення — людині фізично некомфортно, як дверима не грюкнула. Переносне значення — людині психологічно некомфортно, як дверима не грюкнула. Тут — людина груба/незграбна/різка, і ми образно описуємо це «він як дверима не грюкне, то йому не по собі».